# In a Rasch model fit, figure proficiency for which informtation is maximum (where IIC peaks)

Tags: r, plot, max, mle

Given some responses to a fixed number of questions in the form of a table (0v1 for incorrect/correct) and known item difficulties. What I want to do is figure out for what proficiency the item information peaks. The code I have used is:

> **datr<-rasch(dat)
>
> plot(datr,type=c("IIC"),items=c(0))**

The plot looks like this- [image]

The item difficulty parameters are also separately known. I'm pretty new to IRF related stuff and not too confident with exactly what these plots represent. Any help on how to find the ability for which the curve peaks?

**UPDATE.** Part of the response table used (dat):

```
  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10
1  1  1  1  1  0  0  1  1  1   1
2  1  0  0  1  0  0  1  1  1   0
3  1  1  1  1  1  0  1  1  1   1
4  1  1  1  1  1  0  1  1  1   0
5  1  0  1  1  1  0  1  1  1   1
6  1  0  1  1  1  0  0  1  1   0
```

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data using `dput`?

Comment: @Quinten have added a snippet of the table, is this what you meant?